# 27 Directional Lights Celebrate 2024

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Let us celebrate the start of 2024! (1 month late...)

Direct each light (yellow) such that all unlit squares (white) are lit. Walls (black) block light from going through.

[image]

**Some clarifications of the rules:**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COeMq.jpg) are the 8 directions the Lamp can point to.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXtxx.jpg) shows that the Lamp  (labelled as one) can emit light which can pass through other Lamps to light the tiles beside it but cannot emit a light which can pass through a black tile. It cannot be stopped unless it runs into a black tile too.

**The solution is ‘unique’ meaning:**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q4qn.jpg) shows that Lamp 1 CANNOT be chosen to be pointing in the SE direction since it means that Lamp 0 has two viable options to complete the grid and this is disallowed!

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: should be IHATE15CHAR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The completed grid:

> Where N,E,S,W are North East South and West and 1,3,7,9 are NW,NE,SW,SE…

> [image]

A solution path:

> Starting off, there is this obvious deduction we can make where the green tile shows the tile to be lit by a certain lamp in a certain direction and so we can make the deduction of the South Lamp like so…

> [image]

> This leads to some obvious deductions of tiles that can only be lit by one lamp facing one way like so:

> [image]

> Some more obvious deductions (again green just denotes a tile where only one of the lamps at a certain direction can light it):

> [image]

> If we even go far right we can make an easy deduction:

> [image]

Leading to:

> [image: ![enter image description here]

> Then using the rule that whatever placement of a Lamp should only lead to a single deducible solution at the end of the road we cannot have any ‘superfluous lamps’ (which are lamps that are not needed to light a tile) and so we can safely deduce that W lamp is pointing West and the N lamp is pointing North.

> [image]

And

> therefore the 1 Lamp is facing North East and so the E Lamp is Facing East!!

> [image]

And

> Therefore the N lamp is facing North ergo the 3 Lamp is facing NE:

> [image]

Now here come the tricky parts:

> If Lamp 9 is pointing North then it will lead to a result where there are two feasible options (E or W for both lamps) to complete the grid below.

> [image]

> As you can see Lamp 3 is forced to be NE facing meaning Lamp 9 is forced to face SE (due to the superfluous lamp rule just stated). The two Ws being west facing lamps are also forced. 9 can’t be North or South facing otherwise the grid is not completable and so it is forced to face SE… N then is forced to be North facing leaving the two spaces left in the grid… which leads to two options to finish the grid…

> **So Lamp 9 can’t face North** and on top of that it can’t be redundant, so the lamp must face SE!

> With this being the case… then by virtue of an obvious South facing lamp deduction it leads to:

> [image]

> This Lamp in blue cannot be North pointing because it leads to an unsolvable grid… It leads to W facing West, 9 facing SE and so N facing North. But all this then results in one lamp which cannot light the two remaining tiles at once.

> [image]

> so Lamp 9 has to be SE facing to cover the Row 4 tile that was covered by the N lamp above! This then leads us here:

> [image]

> To finish off there is only one way to complete the grid since the bottom W needs to be West facing. Hence we know that we have the right solution since choosing all these options for the Lamps previously leads to no ambiguities arising at the end:

> [image]

Comment: There are three ways to light your first green cell (and in your solution it is lit by all of them). How does that fix the direction of the light above it?

Comment: Oops fixed it thanks for pointing that out